# ¿Como generar números aleatorios impares entre 1 y 9 exceptuando el 5 en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un juego para jugar gato y se tira por numero de casilla (1-9) Necesito hacer una función para generar números aleatorios para que la computadora tire aleatoriamente en las casillas 1,3,7 o 9 pero al intentar crearla tengo el siguiente problema. Anexo el código de prueba antes de hacerlo función.

```
public class Pruebas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int turnoComp=5;//Para guardar el numero 1,3,7 o 9

    while (turnoComp==2&&turnoComp==4&&turnoComp==6&&turnoComp==8&&turnoComp==5) { //mientras el numero sea el que no se necesita
        turnoComp = (int)Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); //guarda en variable el aleatorio
    }
    System.out.println(turnoComp); //verificar que sea el numero que necesito

    //se imprime 5 no el asignado en el while

}
```

No sé como hacer que guarde el numero que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas colocando una condición imposible. En lugar de AND debería ser un OR. Nunca entrará a la rama del WHILE porque su condición nunca se cumple. Traducida al español sería:

mientras (turno es 2 y es 4 y es 6 y es 8 y también es 5)

Un número nunca sera simultáneamente 2 y 4 y 5 etc, debe usar un OR para que sea:

mientras (turno es 2 o es 4 o es 6 o es 8 o es 5)

Comment: Sí, soy principiante y de repente confundo la sintaxis jaja. Me di cuenta al probar el código y ya lo corregí justo como dice. Muchas gracias por la observación.

Answer (score -1):

Aplicando el concepto de recursividad se puede crear la funcion. Un amigo me dio un ejemplo en C y lo aplique en JAVA. Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve.

```
publlic class Aleatorios {
    public static int aletorioImparSin5() {
        int turnoComp = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
        if (turnoComp == 2 || turnoComp == 4 || turnoComp == 6 || turnoComp == 8 || turnoComp == 5) {
        turnoComp = Aleatorios.aletorioImparSin5();
        }
    return turnoComp;
    }
```

}

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras una solución y que la compartas. Sería ideal si pudieras ponerla en modo texto, ya que puede haber usuarios que no puedan ver las imágenes

Comment: Ademas este codigo tiene un problema gravisimo y es que podria dar tranquilamente overflow. Que pasa si nunca encuentra un impar, o si solo encuentra el 5, se sigue llamando eternamente.

Comment: Saludos @Marco bienvenido a Stack y gracias por tus aportes, para un mejor comprension es recomendable usar texto en lugar de una imagen y una explicacion al respecto de ello.